# in Nextjs13 page component accepts props

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i have few questions about this new next13 data fetching approach
this is my home page

```
export default async function Home({ searchParams }: HomeProps) {
  const allCars = await fetchCars({
    manufacturer: searchParams.manufacturer || "",
    year: searchParams.year || 2022,
    fuel: searchParams.fuel || "",
    limit: searchParams.limit || 10,
    model: searchParams.model || "",
  });
```

this is my filter componet

```
export default function CustomFilter({ title, options }: CustomFilterProps) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(options[0]); // State for storing the selected option

  // update the URL search parameters and navigate to the new URL
  const handleUpdateParams = (e: { title: string; value: string }) => {
    const newPathName = updateSearchParams(title, e.value.toLowerCase());

    router.push(newPathName);
  };
```

and this is  my function

```
export const updateSearchParams = (type: string, value: string) => {
  // Get the current URL search params
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

  // Set the specified search parameter to the given value
  searchParams.set(type, value);

  // Set the specified search parameter to the given value
  const newPathname = `${window.location.pathname}?${searchParams.toString()}`;

  return newPathname;
};
```

i have few question about about this next 13 data fetching

1. how the componnet is accepting props ? where does these props are passinbg into it ; how it is possble the comoponet became async
2. why we diidnt use useStatickProps to handle ssr data fetching ?is this appraoch alternative for those next methods ?

3.why in mehthod we are changing the query by directly acceing the window.location , why we dont use react.query={...query , model = 'xyz'}